# How to add custom fields in drupal View?

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-8

I have recently started learning in Drupal. I want to create custom fields type in Drupal view block as showing an image. I am following some reference website and try to make the same

How to make Layout and submenu fields in the view? Any idea or reference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: For custom view field in drupal 7 look here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40520/how-can-i-add-a-field-to-a-view-that-is-calculated-using-other-fields/249005#249005

Comment: cutom field work for me. After long search i found the solution